# The variable $? does not work on $PS1 on mksh

Tags: shell, prompt, mksh

I want my prompt to show the exit status of the last command, so I set my PS1 to this:

```
PS1="$? > "
```

But it always prints `0 >`.
Even when I run `false`, for example, the prompt does not prints `1 >` or whatever the exit status is.

Why does this occur?

EDIT:

I tried to use a function to set my prompt, testing whether the exit status was greater than 0, so it will not print `0 >` always, only when the exit status is nonzero.

```
 promptcmd() {
    _EXIT=$?
    test $_EXIT -gt 0  && printf "\e[1;31m [$_EXIT]"
    printf "\e[0m ❯ "
    unset _EXIT
 }

 PS1="$(promptcmd)"
```

But it also does not work.

Comment: Does `PS1='$? > '` work?

Comment: When I run a wrong command eg--> `many`(in spite of `man`) then I run `PS1="$? > "` which further sets prompt as `127 >` so its working fine for me in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$?` was expanded when you *defined* `PS1`, because you used double quotes.

You can use single quotes to defer expansion until `PS1` is displayed:

```
PS1='$? > '
```

This kind of "double expansion" is not a property of parameters in general, but a result of how the shell uses the value of `PS1`. `echo "$PS1"` will still show the literal string `$? >`, but when the shell displays the prompt, it will expand any parameter expansions found in the value.

Comment: Thanks, the example I gave was just a snipped that I tried to set my PS1 to, I edited the question to put my actual PS1, which also does not work

Comment: Again, `promptcmd` is run when you *define* `PS1`, so you are hard-coding the value of `$?` at that time; you still need single quotes to defer the command substitution. But see the answer for a better way to use `promptcmd`.

Comment: I just set my PS1 to `'$(promptcmd)'` and it worked, thanks. I don't think mksh supports `PROMPT_COMMAND`, this is a bash feature (at least mksh manpage does not mention it).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I keep overlooking that tag.

Comment: Be sure to read the entry for `PS1` in the man page for `mksh` regarding escape sequences. In `bash`, you would wrap them in `\[...\]`; in `mksh`, it looks like you specify a delimiter at the beginning of the prompt that you can use to wrap escape sequences. I don't have `mksh` available to test, though.